# How can I convert all my user inputs to the upper case letter using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

I have a JavaScript function that checks the user input and will compare it against the database.

```
function checkUserInput() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
    var stringToCheckAgainst = random_images_array[num].split('.');

    if (userInput == stringToCheckAgainst[0]) {

        document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = "<p>" + txt.fontsize(5) + "</p>";
        document.close();

    } else {
        //user has inputted an incorrect string
        document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML = "<p>" + txt1.fontsize(5) + "</p>";
        document.close();
    }
}
```

My problem is at the moment this function is case sensitive which means if the user types in “apple” it will return false statements as a fact that all of my objects are named with uppercase letters. 
How can I make my function not case sensitive to works with both lower case and uppercase letters no matter how the user is typing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use like this:

```
if (userInput.toUpperCase() == stringToCheckAgainst[0].toUpperCase()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(cmp_first.toUpperCase()===cmp_second.toUpperCase()){
    alert('Strings are Identical');
}else{
    alert('String mismatch');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
document.write(userInput.toUpperCase());
```

To convert a string to lowercase or uppercase letters, use: **`toLowerCase()`** and **`toUpperCase()`** methods.

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
userInput.toLowerCase() // lowercase
userInput.toUpperCase() // UPPERCASE
```

Answer (score 0):

-Use the toUpperCase() function.

**EXAMPLE:** Desired_string.toUpperCase